# Single Tile Yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, geoserver

Можно ли в Yandex сделать так, чтобы подгружаемый слой (через WMS) не разбивался на тайлы (256х256), а грузился одним тайлом (bbox)? При просмотре слоя на GeoServer 
[image: слой на GeoServer] все рисуется корректно. При отрисовке на клиенте получается так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если предоставите ссылку на пример, то помочь будет легче. А так кажется, что они просто нарезаны неправильно. Конечно, вы можете наложить одной картинкой https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon_with_image , но хорошо не получится. Тайлы можно подготовить ещё так https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/archive/jsapi/1.x/dg/concepts/ymapstiler-docpage/

Comment: За основу взял пример от dimik https://github.com/dimik/ymaps/blob/master/layer-wms/layer-wms.js

Comment: данные из shp-файлов или PostGIS отоброжаются корректно. Конкретно в этом примере точки из таблицы PostGIS плюс SLD-стили.

Comment: пример SLD https://wiki.state.ma.us/display/massgis/GeoServer+-+WMS+and+WPS+-+Rendering+Transformations+-+Heatmap

Comment: такой технологии к сожалению не знаю. Как вариант, могу предложить ещё тепловые карты https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/security_cameras